# Adding existing source packages to a Maven Web Application in Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans

I have a normal Netbeans project, and I would like to add the source packages of this project to a project that is a Maven Web Application, also within Netbeans.

I tried copy-pasting the packages into the /src project directory of the Maven application, but this doesn't seem to work.

Could someone please tell me how I could do this ?

If this is not possible, could someone tell me if I can convert the entire normal project into a Maven Web Application ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add the dependency to your web-application instead of the source code, cause maven is intended to handle exactly such situations.

Comment: You mean I can add source packages also as a dependency ? I didn't know that. I am new to Maven so I am very grateful for your help. Thank you :)

Comment: You can add the source code as a dependency but you should, cause you need it use compiled class out of it. So you use it as a dependency which means in other words the created jar.